# Testar classes JQuery

Tags: jquery

Eu sei que para testar se um elemento possui uma classe usamos o hasClass(), mas minha dúvida é a seguinte.
Tenho um elemento com uma classe e atribuo uma segunda classe nele com classToggle(). Existe uma forma de testar se uma classe possui uma outra classe?
Se ficou confuso estarei respondendo e editando tudo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei se isso responde totalmente sua pergunta, mas você pode recuperar as classes da seguinte forma.

Exemplo:

***HTML***

```
<div id="minhaDiv" class="classe1 classe2 classe3"></div>
```

***JS***

```
var classes = document.getElementById("minhaDiv").className.split(' ');
console.log(classes);
```

ou

***Jquery***

```
var classes = $("#minhaDiv").attr("class").split(' ');
console.log(classes);
```

A variável será populada com um *Array* contendo todas as classes que estão setadas no elemento.

Resultado (Console)

> ["classe1", "classe2", "classe3"]

**[DEMO - Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/5w9kg/1/)**

E caso o navegador de suporte ao [element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList), basta fazer desta forma que o resutaldo será o mesmo.

Exemplo 2:

**JS**

```
var classes = document.getElementById("minhaDiv").classList;
console.log(classes);
```

**[DEMO - Exemplo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/5w9kg/2/)**